# Shrink size of braces in big formula

Tags: size, rendering

I have the following formula in my latex document.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $\mathcal{D}_{\left\{\ddots_{\{\beta, \dots\}}\right\}}$
\end{document}
```

The curly braces are rendered quit big to towards the bottom of the line, as you can see her:

[image] [image]

why isn't it rendered like following example? Is there any way of shrinking the curly braces in this case?

Comment: To possibly answer your question, I'm not a big fan of using `\left\{...\right\}` because they often give delimiters that asre too large for my tastes. Instead, I use `\bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Bigl`, `\Biggl` and `\bigr`, `\biggr`, `\Bigr`, `\Biggr` from the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package as they give better control over the delimiter sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use a combination of the comment by @Andrew and the answer of @Bernard.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{D}_{\bigl\{\rule{0pt}{2ex}\smash{\ddots}_{\{\beta, \dots\}}\bigr\}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathcal{D}_{\begin{Bmatrix}\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}\smash[t]{\ddots}_{\{\beta, …\}}\end{Bmatrix}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the `Bmatrix` environment, the `\rule` command and the `\smash` command do?

Comment: `Bmatrix` is a matrix with braces as delimiters (it's defined in `amsmath`, along with `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `vmatrix`and  `Vmatrix`. `\smash[t]`maths the height (but not the depth) of its content equal to 0. As the braces were a little too tight, I added and invisible rule (width 0pt) with a suitable height  (2.4ex) to make them less tight.